# is bleach residue (after evaporation) safe?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have been preparing bleach disinfectant lately in a spray bottle and has been spraying on my couch, door mat, door knots, etc... 
I don't rinse it... So I assume there is bleach residue left after evaporation?
Is it safe to leave the residue?

I felt some very mild burn like feeling on my arms when putting my arms on my couch lately; I don't know if this is some kind of placebo effect or if it is real.

Comment: Liquid bleaches are stable in highly alkaline solution. You should not be spraying it on couches. If you are feeling irritation, wipe the couches with a wet towel (in warm water) several times. Let them air dry. There is no need to be afraid or panic out of the current situation. Caution and patience is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Bleach, especially employed in laundry applications, may have, in addition to the active ingredient sodium hypochlorite (NaOCl), an equal concentration of NaCl (as it is prepared from the action of Cl2 on NaOH) and at times, an alkaline, like lye (NaOH) or Washing Soda (sodium carbonate, Na2CO3). The latter can cause skin rashes and irritation (and will be present on drying).

The rationale for the latter is to keep the pH elevated in aqueous sodium hypochlorite as upon exposure to CO2, there is the possible introduction of hypochlorous acid. While HOCl is more powerful (and reportedly [nearly a hundred times more potent disinfectant](https://www.aquaox.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/HOCL-Efficacy.pdf) than the associated hypochlorite) is far less stable (a short shelf-life). Further, the decomposition product is O2 and also HCl (and not NaCl).

The created hydrochloric acid can further react with the sodium hypochlorite or hypochlorous acid as follows:

$\ce{HCl + NaOCl -> NaCl + HOCl}$

$\ce{HCl + HOCl <=> Cl2 + H2O}$

leading to a chain decomposition of the bleach, hence the advantage of adding NaOH or Na2CO3. To quote the cited source:

> The pH has a significant effect on the stability of sodium hypochlorite solutions. Below pH 11 the decomposition of sodium hypochlorite is significant due to the shift in the equilibrium in favor of the more reactive hypochlorous acid. A pH between 12 and 13 gives the most stable solution. This equates to 0.4 to 4.0 grams per liter (gpl) excess NaOH. Greater concentrations will not improve the stability. Excessively high improve the stability. Excessively high alkalinity will damage textiles and retard the bleaching and disinfecting actions of the hypochlorite.

I would suggest that you can even dilute your current NaOCl dosing and add some lemon juice, just prior to use, to create (per the source reference noted above) a much more powerful mix (and a more potent bleaching agent, so be careful where you select to employ it) albeit, with a much shorter shelf-life.

To rapidly remove bleach smell (likely Cl2O from the dehydration of HOCl), one can apply a spray of dilute H2O2, which rapidly converts NaOCl to NaCl and oxygen. Caution: this further promotes bleaching action via intermediate radical formation (see ['Hydroxyl radical from the reaction between hypochlorite and hydrogen peroxide'](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230651663_Hydroxyl_radical_from_the_reaction_between_hypochlorite_and_hydrogen_peroxide)), so again be careful where you apply it.

Comment: @ Ajkoer. All you say is exact, but these rections happens in a solution of bleach. If the laundry is dry, these reactions will simply not happen, because NaClO is decomposed when dry. So there is no risk of having HOCl, Cl2 or Cl2O in Yeoman's laundry.

Comment: I did also say that NaOH (using in the prep of bleach) and perhaps Na2CO3 could be leftover upon evaporation. NaCl is also found and I explained how from its prep. Also explained why one would want to make the bleach more alkaline. And yes, I added some side comments on how to remove bleach smell with H2O2.

Comment: I also went off-topic and discussed the conversion of the NaOCl with weak lemon juice to the 80 to 100 times more powerful (including in disinfecting per the provided reference) hypochlorous acid, HOCl, which is albeit more unstable, so this implies a time-of-use decision.

Answer (score -2):

Bleach is usually a mixed solution of sodium hypochlorite NaClO and a lot of sodium chloride NaCl. NaClO is decomposed when dry. So your couch is probably soaked in salt (NaCl). It may produce an uncomfortable feeling.

Comment: so it is not dangerous right? with what's going atm I am kinda paranoid and trying to disinfecting everything

Comment: It is not dangerous. But it may be disagreeable.